# How to change the keyboard type for a text field in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitextfield, xcode4

I created a text field in XCode, not Interface Builder. In IB you can select different keyboard types. How can you do the same thing in XCode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the [`keyboardType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-SW12) property?

Answer (score 0):

1) In xib you can change by clicking the Keyboard type like below

[image]

2) Programmatically you can set by textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;