# How to switch keyboard between number+punctuation input view and letter input view with code?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to switch between number input view and letters input view of UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable with code? I want to show the number input view by default but allow user to input character as well.
I need

Comment: Asked and answered a lot here.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790540/how-to-change-the-keyboard-type-for-a-text-field-in-xcode

Comment: No. To be clarified, I want to use the keyboard type: UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable as I need allow user to input both number and characters. But I want to show numbers instead of letters to user by default. I don't see this is mentioned in the link provided.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry.  I think the answer is you can't, but I'd be happy to find out that I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to simulate the pressing of the `123` key on the iPhone keyboard to switch between the numbers/symbols and the letters of the keyboard.

What you can do is switch between two different keyboard types though. Example:

```
someTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable; // start with one type
```

Then when you want to switch you can do:

```
- (void)toggleKeyboardType:(UITextField *)textfield {
    if (textfield.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation) {
        textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    } else {
        textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    }
    [textfield reloadInputViews];
}
```

Comment: Instead of resigning and then becoming first responder, `[textField reloadInputViews]` will update the keyboard type and appearance and input accessory view all in place without calling `textField:should/will/did end/begin editing` as well as it won't call Notification Center.

Comment: @Fennelouski Good call. I forgot about that method.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. Then I need add an extra button onto the two InputViews to do the toggle thing.